# Can parameters passed to `replot` replace previous plot parameters?

Tags: gnuplot

The `replot` command can take new plot parameters and output a new plot over the previous one. This is possible because [the docs](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node150.html) say that there is an implicit comma between the previous plot and any arguments passed to `replot`.

Is there a setting that will take new parameters and instead apply them directly to the previous plot, or overwrite the previous parameters?

For example, say I plot:

`plot sin(x)`

But now I want to plot it with dots. Is there a way to modify this plot with this?

`replot with dots`

This type of syntax would make it easier for me to iterate on a single plot interactively until it's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.  But you can change the default plot style or the properties of the lines and then replot:

```
set style function points
plot sin(x)
set style function lines
replot
set style function linespoints
replot
set linetype 1 pointtype 7 pointinterval 5
replot
```

[image]